# Inputting a formula through loop into a cell via referenced value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-formula

This was very confusing so now I have it down to something more manageable. Starting on the current sheet:

1. Select D2 and Select down to the last filled cell
2. Go through each cell in the Range and check to the cell to the right if the value is "Yes"
3. If this value is "Yes" : Go to the 'Master Trainings' sheet
4. Search down Column A for the cell with the same text value. Go to the cell ot the right and store that value in an array
5. If it cannot be found in this sheet: Go to the 'PROSPECT' sheet
6. Again, search down Column A and look to the cell to the right and store that value in the array.
7. At this point, it should be an array as the same size as the beginning Range.
8. Go back to the original sheet and sum all of the values of the array in cell "D26"

### This is what I have so far to attempt to loop everything through for the first range

```
Dim Training As Range
Dim cel As Range
Range("F2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Set Training = Selection
For Each cel In Training.Cells
    If cel.Value = "Yes" Then


    Else
Next cel
```

Comment: That's a lot to ask in 1 post. I would suggest that you cut your question down to first checking the column value in column D and if not then check column A in `Master Trainings` sheet. Just as a starting point, you don't need to do that with VBA. You could have a formula to do that for you. You can use VBA to populate your range with the formula

Comment: That's rather confusing. Your text refers to D, your code to F. What do you want to find in the other sheet? A screenshot might help.

Comment: I am going to keep working on it, but I hope this helps!